# Discord.js reaction collector wont work with custom emojis

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been having a problem while coding my bot where my reaction collector will work with Unicode emojis, but not my server's custom emojis. I want the reaction to send a message into the channel. It currently only works with Unicode emojis. Is there a certain way I should be doing this?

````
        .then(collected => {
          const reaction = collected.first();

          if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
            message.channel.send("Smile")
            
          }
          
          if (reaction.emoji.name === "<:Peasant:797613974173515786>") {
            message.channel.send("Peasant")
          }
        
          
        })```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `awaitReactions` method, then your promise is unfulfilled. [Check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for more info. To solve this, **all you have to do is add `return` to your program**, thus fulfilling the promise.

Instead of `message.channel.send("Smile")` and `message.channel.send("Peasant")`, send `return message.channel.send("Smile")` and `return message.channel.send("Peasant")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue recently,but luckily I figured it out!

Simply set reaction.emoji.name to the actual name of the emoji,and not the text you use for displaying the emoji. For example,in your case,it would be:

```
if (reaction.emoji.name == 'Peasant') {
   // do stuff
}
```

And in some hypothetical case,if the text for another emoji was <:hypotheticalemojiname:837837383738373>,the way to check if the reaction was that emoji would be:

```
if (reaction.emoji.name == 'hypotheticalemojiname') {
   // Do stuff
}
```

Hope this helped!